# Cannot set input field with type password and autocomplete using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cefsharp, jquery-widgets

I am working on an automatic login feature by filling in the username and password for a web application using javascript. The password field has the autocomplete feature activated. It's HTML is as below -

```
<input name="autofill_password" type="password" style="display:none">
<input name="user_password" type="text" onfocus="this.setAttribute('type', 'password')" id="user_password" maxlength="256" class="loginField" autocomplete="new-password">
```

I am unable to set the value using javascript or jquery for the "user_password" field.
I have tried the following with no luck -

```
$('#user_password').val("g");
$('#user_password').attr('value', 'new value');
document.getElementById('user_password').value = 'Welcome!1';
document.getElementById('user_password').setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

What is preventing the setting of the value and what else can I try?

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1o5hztg9/. Check the console for errors

Comment: Also, having an auto-complate feature on a password field in client-side JS seems like an incredibly bad idea for security.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan [just to showcase that all three approaches work](https://jsbin.com/viruhukuxu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Autocomplete on a password field is probably going to be complicated and browser specific.  Why not use the autocomplete features already built into browsers and plugins like Lastpass?

Comment: Actually we are trying to automate navigation and input into a portal with no access to the source code

Comment: From the analysis, we see that it uses Jquery widgets for login fields. Could this having some implications?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is for all the other simpletons like me, the issue was, that there was a label with the same id as password field.